# Using weblogic.Admin in weblogic 12c

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to check the status of Weblogic server in 12c using the below command which works properly in 10.X weblogic

**java weblogic.Admin -url t3://$IP:$Port GETSTATE -username $username -password $password**

But in 12c version, wlst (java weblogic.WLST) commands are working fine. But while using weblogic.Admin, getting the error as "**Could not find or load main class weblogic.Admin**"

I have set my classpath as follows
export CLASSPATH=$WL_HOME/server/lib/weblogic.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

weblogic.Admin tool is deprecated since version 9 and is no longer available in 12c. You have to use wlst.